# Swiperjs navigation arrows inside the slider

Tags: html, angular, typescript, swiper.js

I have a swiperjs slider implemented in Angular. In other cases, you can just put the navigation code outside the container element of the swiper. In Angular, however, things are a bit different. I tried using CSS, but that doesnt help. It just moves out of view and starts getting cropped from the outside.

[image]

HTML code:

```
<swiper [class.d-none]="!(showRecommendations$ | async)"
    [slidesPerView]="2"
    [spaceBetween]="10"
    [navigation]="true"
    [breakpoints]="{
        '992': {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 10
        }
      }"
>
     <ng-template swiperSlide 
    *ngFor="let gift of (gifts$ | async); let i = index">...
    </ng-template>

</swiper>
```

TS code:

```
import SwiperCore, { Navigation } from "swiper/core";

...

SwiperCore.use([Navigation])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <swiper [class.d-none]="!(showRecommendations$ | async)"
      [slidesPerView]="2"
      [spaceBetween]="10"
      navigation="navigation:  {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      }"
      [breakpoints]="{
          '992': {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 10
          }
        }"
  >
      <ng-template swiperSlide 
      *ngFor="let gift of (gifts$ | async); let i = index">...
      </ng-template>
  </swiper>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
<div>
```

make sure to set a position relative for the wrapper  element as i have done in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just tried it, but the error                                                                     "Error: Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
Statement:  { nextEl: '.swiper-button-next', prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev' }" is shown. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sarmad i forgot to remove the brackets around [navigation], answer has been fixed

Comment: Still does not work. Navigation directive without the quotes is not an option for the swiper js component.